# How to add a facebook like button on php /css pages?

Tags: php, css, facebook

Basically my website's pages are all .php and my stylesheet is.css how can I add a facebook like button. When I use the facebook developers page the codes available are: HTML5, XFBML, IFRAME and url. Would any of these be compatible with my website? I know where to paste the correct code (if any are compatible) in my footer.php file but where should I paste the other code as the facebook site says it needs to be just after the  tag which I don't have....

I'm using wordpress so have no access to any html pages anyways...

Any help/suggestions would be more than welcome!

Comment: The tag that you think you don't have, you do have.  Every page has it, it's probably inside something like "header.php"

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ to create your button. Do your settings as you wish, and then click `Get Code`. Select the `IFRAME` code and paste it wherever you want your button to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a like button yourself, you should dig in your footer.php (found in your template) and add the javascript code in your header.php.
If you are not familiar with the structure of wordpress, you could just use a plugin, like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-like-button/

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and light is to use `HTML5` version of fb like button.